# bevel modifier is not working properly

Tags: modeling

I am watching from a tutorial but I am not following it exactly so I can do it myself but I ran into the bevel modifier issue which did not yield the same result as shown in the tutorial.
this is the tutorial's result
[image]

as you can see the guard of the sword has bent edges mine however do not
[image]

here is a link the tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=saxpjudV_88&t=1091s
he did the bevel modifier at around 36:03
I am uploading the link of my project in the comments

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/S9vQkKZP/

Comment: my project link*

Answer (score 2):

There are duplicated vertices: in edit mode, select all and use <kbd>M</kbd> to merge then *"by distance"*.

[image]

Comment: thank you for the third time you have helped me a lot lemon.

Comment: You are welcome but please you should accept the answer if they are good for you, mines and the others of course. There is a button on the left of the answer for that. It gives some points to us and also helps getting the site organized. Thanks.